# Permission problems with a mounted NTFS VM volume

Tags: virtual-machine, mount, ntfs, file-permissions, vmware-player

I’m trying to migrate a VMPlayer system to VirtualBox, but the migration isn’t working (I’ve already spent hours trying the small handful of solutions people have suggest and eventually given up). As a workaround, I am trying to manually migrate by installing Windows in VirtualBox and copy the important files over, then discard the VMPlayer system.

The problem now is that I cannot access the files. I cannot copy the files from within the VM because they are in use, so I tried shutting down the VM and mounting its hard-drive as a virtual volume on the host system. This always worked just fine in the old days when I was using FAT32, but the VM drive is now NTFS, so I am unable to access the files.

Here’s a simplified outline of the situation:

- Required files are stored in `Bob` user in XP VM
- VM’s drive is stored on host in `C:\VMs\XP.vmdk`
- VM drive is successfully mounted in host as `Z:\` via `vmware-mount.exe z: c:\vms\xp.vmdk`
- Host correctly sees VM’s drive as NTFS volume `Z:\`
- Cannot access files in `Z:\Documents and Settings\Bob` (because of permissions)
- Running `takeown /f z:\documents and settings\bob` from a non-elevated command-prompt returns the following error as though the drive is not NTFS (even though the host Windows 7 and the guest XP both say it is):

  > ERROR: File ownership cannot be applied on insecure file systems; there is no support for ACLs.
- Running the same command from an elevated command-prompt doesn’t work either because it cannot see `Z:\` at all!
- Using the *Security* tab from Windows Explorer doesn’t work because every action (granting permissions, taking ownership, etc.) always gives a permission error

Does anyone know what’s wrong (why I’m getting such inconsistent results) and how to deal with it?

Comment: (I can likely work around this specific issue by creating a temporary admin user account in the VM, granting it permissions to the “Bob” account, logging out of “Bob”, into the temp admin, copying the files, logging out of the temp, back into “Bob”, and deleting the temp. It’s lots of time-consuming, unnecessary work, but it should work for this. However, it doesn’t help if you need to access system files like the registry hives in `c:\windows\system32\config` because those also need permissions, but you can’t use the temp-user trick. That would require *even more* time and work to deal with.)

Comment: The main problem seems to be the layer between the virtual disk and the host file system (i.e. the driver used to mount it). For what is worth, the `takeown` command works fine with VHD files once they're mounted. As for the workaround, you can copy in-use files through [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: The problem isn’t the VHD files, it’s their *contents* when mounted. Yes, you may be able to copy *some* in-use files, but that’s not always good enough. For example, when I want to shrink the VMDK file, I need to delete the giant pagefile which is not possible while the VM is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr make sure to mount the virtual disk from an elevated command-prompt and do all of your cleanup from that same prompt.**

While trying to look at the details of what does and doesn’t work and when and how, it suddenly occurred to me that the key is that I cannot see the mounted volume at all from an elevated command-prompt. I had mounted the virtual disk from a normal command-prompt, and even though it makes no sense that an elevated command-prompt would be unable to see something created from a regular (limited) account since the admin account should have superior access, I figured I would try mounting the virtual disk from an elevated prompt.

Et voila!

I now had access to the mounted virtual disk from an elevated-prompt. I was now able to delete files, defragment, wipe free space, un-mount, and shrink the volume with ease.

I still don’t understand why the admin account was unable to see the mounted drive, nor why it is possible to mount the virtual disk from a limited account, but at least it works.

**NB**: you *must* do all of your cleanup work from the **same** elevated-prompt as the one in which you mounted the virtual disk. I discovered the hard way that if you close that command-prompt, opening a new one, even an elevated one, would no longer have access to the mounted volume (I could only un-mount it). It is truly bizarre that the mounted volume (using `vmware-mount.exe`) has such accessibility problems.